# Python. Списки в словаре

Tags: python, list

Есть такой словарь:

```
l = {
    "settings": [
        [
            "Офис","applications-office",18, #0

            ["CAT 1.1: Program Name Title","program-name",1],
            ["CAT 1.2: Program Name For Root","program-name-root",0],
            ["CAT 1.3: Program Name For Root","program-name-root",0],
        ],

        [
            "Настройки","applications-office",18, #0

            ["CAT 2.1: Program Name Title","program-name",1],
            ["CAT 2.2: Program Name For Root","program-name-root",0],
            ["CAT 2.3: Program Name For Root","program-name-root",0],
        ],
    ],
}
```

Нужно получить все заголовки из внутренних списков:

- CAT 1.1: Program Name,
- CAT 1.2: Program name,
- ... ,
- CAT 2.3: Program name*

Comment: Что пробовали сделать, что не получилось?

Comment: Из l берете значение по ключу settings, получаете список, этот список прогоняете в цикле и из значения по индексам достаете нужное вам. Для проверки пишете значения в print

Comment: @soon Делал так:

for i in range(len([i[0] for i in root])):
print(i,root[i][3:])

Но именно заголовки (Program name) получить не могу.

Comment: @CockLobster добавьте лучше информацию о попытках (что сделали, с какой мыслью, что вывело вместо ожидаемого) в сам вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in l.keys():                        # Перебор всех ключей словаря
    for i in range(len(l[k])):            # Перебор всех подмассивов по ключу
        for j in range(3, len(l[k][i])):  # Перебор элементов подмассива, содержащих нужный текст
            print(l[k][i][j][0])          # Вывод результата
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
 ls = []
 for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,6):
        if type(l['settings'][i][j]) == type(ls):
            print(l['settings'][i][j][0], ' ', l['settings'][i][j][1])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.